# I can't use a variable outside of Wordpress shortcode function

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I want to develop a plugin to add the ability to do something with shortcode. I want it to function like this:

```
[shortcode]Content[/shortcode]
```

Here is the code I use:

```
function quote( $atts, $content = null ) {  
    return '<div class="right text">"'.$content.'"</div>';  
}

add_shortcode("quote", "quote");
```

The $content variable, which returns the value of the shortcode, in this case Content, cannot be used outside of the function. I want to use it on some other part of the PHP code, but I can't get it to work. I am not experienced with PHP, so if you have any solution, please try to be as clear as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to declare it as a global variable otherwise it's scope (where you can access it) is limited to the function you're using it in.

```
function quote( $atts, $content = null ) {  
global $content;
return '<div class="right text">"'.$content.'"</div>';  
}
```

add_shortcode("quote", "quote");

echo "Using content somewhere else $content";

FYI though, it can lead to potential problems. $content, for example, is a pretty common variable and could conflict if the same variable is being used elsewhere. You'd be better off giving it a unique name like: global $my_global_content = $content. Then use $my_global_$content in the other areas of your code.